# Create a enum or enum equivalent that returns string (enum returns int) in .NET

Tags: vb.net, string, enums

I have a URL, lets say `http://www.example.com`.  Sometimes, I need to send HTTP and other times, I need to send HTTPS.  For that, I created an enum:

```
Private _protocol As Protocol

Enum Protocol
    HTTP
    HTTPS
End Enum

Public Property protocolType() As Protocol
    Get
        Return _protocol
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Protocol)
        _protocol = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Now, when I get the value back from protocoltype, it returns an integer value as enum.  How do I get the string name of an enum.

```
 Dim targetUri As String = setting.protocolType & "://www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the string value of the Enum, use [Enum.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx)

Comment: Thanks lot. i thought it will convert like 2 to "2"  int to string(int)